# Why is my proc format changing unrelated variables?

Tags: sas, format, proc

This is my proc format code:

```
Proc format;
value $fmtempty
" " = "unknown"
;
run;
```

This is my application to the data set:

```
DATA ASSIGN1.TRAININGCOPY;

SET TRAININGCOPY;

FORMAT job education $fmtempty.;

RUN;
```

At first it seemed to work but the table just comes out "goofy".

1. it cuts of the names of the rest of my variables, ex management becomes managem
2. when I run this code:

   proc freq data= ASSIGN1.TRAINING;
   tables job;
   run;

for job, my frequency empty goes from 4 to 42.  oddly, when I visually inspect and filter the data, the missing data has been filled in as expected, and I can't find any missing data.  I have similar results with education.

```
original          converts to
1   blue-collar  1 bluec
2                2 unknown      
3   management   3 managem  
4   student      4 stude
5   technician   5 techni
6   blue-collar  6 bluec
```

Any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong or even an explanation of what's actually happening would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: What length do the variables JOB and EDUCATION have? Why not just be explicit about how many characters you want in your FORMAT statement? Or set a default width when defining the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `Proc FORMAT` `value` statement to use the `(default=N)` option.  N defines how much width to allocate for the format when no width is specified in a `FORMAT` statement.

Example:

```
data have;
input text $char20.;
datalines;
blue-collar
            
management 
student    
technician 
blue-collar
;

proc format;
  value $fmtempty (default=20)
    " " = "unknown"
  ;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  format text $fmtempty.;
run;
```

Output data set
[image]